# .NET Core Library reference to .Net core Web project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Getting following error when i try to add reference of .net core library reference in my web app.

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The following projects are not supported as references :

- DiscoverLib has target frameworks that are incompatible with targets in current project DiscoverWeb.

DiscoverWeb: .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2

DiscoverLib: .NETStandard,Version=v1.6

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's expected/normal. .NETStandard 1.6 requires .NET Framework 4.6.3 (aka vNext) which is an unreleased version of the .NET Framework.

See [this](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) matrix for information. If you want to target .NET Framework 4.5.1 your class library must be ".NET Standard 1.2" or lower. This reduce the number of API you can use, so you always need to balance between minimum version supported and newest API.